# Can you import Spriter Pro 2d rigged sprites to LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, game-physics

as it says, I've read online about Spine being imported over to LibGDX. I'm using Android Studio to develop a game and using the LibGDX framework. But my game requires 2D rigged animation than the pre-rendered models so I'm using Spriter Pro. But I want to know how do I import what I make from Spriter Pro to LibGDX so I can use what I make from there to develop my game on the LibGDX framework.

and if anyone could elaborate, couldn't a 2d animation with lots of frames be just as efficient as a 2d rigged animation? I dont see the pros and cons for both, just that 2d animation could take up alot of time to make

Comment: First hit on Google: https://github.com/Trixt0r/spriter, also links to a detailed tutorial for what looks like exactly your use-case. If that doesn't help then please consider being more specific and carefully read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

[This Library might work for you](https://github.com/Trixt0r/spriter)
I'm currently trying to implement this library in my own project but I'm still having strange problems as seen below:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiGtN.png)

I hope it helps and please contact me if you get it implemented in libGDX without this problem.

edit: sorry Xoppa, did not see your comment

Answer (score 0):

In addition o the already mentioned https://github.com/Trixt0r/spriter repository you may want to try out https://github.com/blueacorn/libgdx-spriter-demo for some simple ready-to-go implementations of the necessary loaders and drawers. The [readme](https://github.com/blueacorn/libgdx-spriter-demo#libgdx--spriter-demonstration) includes an easy tutorial for quick results.